# Magento:constructing product URL

Tags: magento

I have been able to get attributes like name, image URL, description from a magento store. However getting the product URL is tedious. Any help?? Thanks.

```
include_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$products->load(); 
    $baseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);

    foreach ($products as $id => $product):
   $output .= '
   <product>
   <name><![CDATA['. $product['name'] .']]></name>
   <description><![CDATA['. $product['description'] .']]></description>
   <url>'. $product['url_key'] .'</url>
   <image>'. $baseUrl ."media/catalog/product". $product['image'] .'</image>';
   </product>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product URL is just:

```
$product->getProductUrl()
```

In fact, it is better if you use the getters and setters instead of array access on Magento objects because it allows other developers to provide overrides in a conventional way. So instead of `$product['description']` please use `$product->getDescription()`. It will avoid problems in future.

Comment: thanks clockwisegeek. It prints out URL but it appends my file name to it. eg. I saved my code as magento.php and getProductUrl() gives me http://www.dcommerce.com/magento.php/catalog/product/view/id/18/s/sony-ericsson-w810i/?SID=64f2094f58efbafa89156c8d5127ef8c. How do i get the exact url without respect to my magento.php file?

Comment: You for that you need to turn on URL rewrites in _System > Configuration > Web > Search Engines Optimization_

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calculating the base URL yourself you can simply use:

```
'<image'>.Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product).'</image>'
```

The helper has a `__toString()` function built in so automatically produces the URL when used as a string. It will also take care of watermarks, resizing, cropping and all the other things you normally see in action but take for granted.

Comment: thanks. I was talking about product urls. (exact links to the products)